# Cartthrob 3 : notification email sent is blank when order as a guest is made

Tags: cartthrob, email, ee3, notification

I made my tests of order frequently (connected as super-admin) and everything was fine with the notification emails when an order was placed (email sent to the customer and email sent to the admin).

I disconnected from CP, to check really as a guest and then the email notiications (both admin and customer) arrived completely blank...

What I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cartthrob version : 3.0.2
EE version : 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing all your tags and just having static text in the email as a test? And if that works, can you add your tags back one by one to see if a specific ones is causing the problem?